# Rabbitmq memory control, queue is full and is not paging. Connection hangs

Tags: python, memory, pagination, rabbitmq, celery

I'm testing out a rabbitMQ, celery setup.

In the current setup there is a jobqueue (2GB RAM, 65GB HD) and only one worker which pushes a lot of messages to the queue (later, we'll add a bunch of workers). When the jobqueue reaches about ~11 million messages the connection hangs (pretty sure this is a case of `blocking` due to Memory Based Flow Control as in http://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html). But the connection hangs forever, never closing the connection, nor paging to disk. This is undesirable behavior -- causing the celery workers to become zombie processes.

In thinking about the total size that system might actually require -- we would like the queue to be able to take something like 10,000 times  this load -- a total max of around ~30billion messages in the queue at a time.

Here are some relevant settings:

```
{vm_memory_high_watermark,0.8},
{vm_memory_high_watermark_paging_ratio,0.5}]
```

We initially changed the vm_high_watermark from .4 to .8, which allowed more messages in the queue but still not enough.

We're thinking of course the system will need more RAM at some point, although before that happens we want to understand the current problem and how to deal with it.

Right now, there are only 11m tasks in the queue and it is using 80% of 2GB RAM, and the entire system is only using 8GB of disk. The memory usage makes sense given that we set the `vm_memory_high_watermark` to .8. The disk usage does not make sense at all to me, though -- and suggests that the paginating is not happening. Why isn't RabbitMQ paginating to disk in order to allow the queue to grow more? While obviously slowing down the queue machine, this would allow it to not die -- and seems like desirable fallback behavior. AFAIK this is indeed the whole point of pagination.

Other notes:

We confirmed that the connections are hanging and have in fact been blocked for 41 hours since then (by examining the connections section of  `rabbitmqctl report`). According to http://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html this means that "flow control is taking place". The question is -- why isn't it paging messages to disk?

Other details:

Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

RabbitMQ 3.2.2, Erlang R14B04

Celery 3.0.24

Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your queue is not durable, no messages will be paged to disk. The system will be limited by available memory. IF you need messages to be flushed to disk, use a `durable=true` queue.

And this design, having a lot of load and not consuming the messages, is not ideal. RabbitMQ is not a database, the messages are meant to be transient. IF you need a datastore, use Redis, a RDBMS, etc.

Comment: What about the paging threshold? Wouldn't RMQ page out its queues, durable or not, if the Paging Threshold was hit as per https://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html?

Comment: @mhamrah Yes, if RabbitMQ is suffering from memory pressure, then it will try to page queue contents to disk even if those messages were not set as persistent originally.